# C++ Understanding traversal of another programmers B Tree

Tags: c++, database, data-structures

I have a B-tree which already exists in the database. Now the following piece of code which is written by some other programmer tries to traverse the B-Tree. However, I am unable to understand as to what is the use of the functions: readInner1(page,slot) and readInnerPage(page,slot). Can someone help me in understanding what the code does by using these 2 functions?

```
static inline unsigned readUint32Aligned(const unsigned char* data) { return toHost(*reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(data)); }

/// The page remains accessible during the lifetime of the BufferReference object.
class BufferReference
{
   public:
   /// The size of a page
   static const unsigned pageSize = 16384;
   /// A page buffer
   struct PageBuffer { char data[pageSize]; };

   private:
   /// The buffer frame
   const BufferFrame* frame;

   /// No copying of references
   BufferReference(const BufferReference&);
   void operator=(const BufferReference&);

   public:
   /// Constructor
   BufferReference();
   /// Constructor from a request
   BufferReference(const BufferRequest& request);
   /// Destructor
   /// Access the page
   const void* getPage() const;
   /// Get the page number
   unsigned getPageNo() const;
};


Info1(unsigned root,unsigned value1)
{
   // Traverse the B-Tree
#define readInner1(page,slot) readUint32Aligned(page+24+8*(slot))
#define readInnerPage(page,slot) readUint32Aligned(page+24+8*(slot)+4)
   BufferReference ref;
   ref=readShared(root);
   while (true) {
      const unsigned char* page=static_cast<const unsigned char*>(ref.getPage());
      // Inner node?
      if (readUint32Aligned(page+8)==0xFFFFFFFF) {
         // Perform a binary search. The test is more complex as we only have the upper bound for ranges
         unsigned left=0,right=readUint32Aligned(page+16);
         cout<<"\n right="<<right<<"\n";
         while (left!=right) {
            unsigned middle=(left+right)/2;
            printf("\n MIDDLE=%d",middle);
            unsigned middle1=readInner1(page,middle);
            cout<<"\n middle1="<<middle1<<"\t value1="<<value1<<"\n";
            if (value1>middle1) {
               left=middle+1;
               cout<<"\n left="<<left<<"\n";
            } else if ((!middle)||(value1>readInner1(page,middle-1))) {
               ref=readShared(readInnerPage(page,middle));
               break;
            } else {
               right=middle;
               cout<<"\n right="<<right<<"\n";
            }
         }
         // Unsuccessful search?
         if (left==right) {
            ref.reset();
            return false;
         }
      } else {
         // A leaf node
         break;
      }
   }
#undef readInnerPage
#undef readInner1
}
```

Also it will be great if someone could explain the code?

Comment: I love how that programmer added a comment `/// Constructor` above the obvious constructor declaration and similar things, but doesn't spend a single line one explaining his hack, erm, construction for retrieving data...

Comment: Horrible use of macros there, the scope of which is global, and not confined to the function. The syntax error of Info1 is not C++ either, so that must be a macro too.

Comment: @CashCow is that true? does the #undef at the end not work?

Comment: Yeah the undef will undefine them. So it will only "break" if the macros are used elsewhere and are still defined in which case you will get a compiler error for redefining a macro. Inline function is still preferable. Not putting the implementation in a header even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in general is performing a binary search.

Thus `left` and `right` are bounds to the search, and this halves every iteration until they hold the same value.

The data seems to be arranged in pages of 16K bytes, and there is probably some header information within those pages, which are probably sorted and thus it is checking these values then readjusting the search.

If you are allowed to modify the code may I suggest you replace the macros with inline functions.

Answer (score 0):

Macros `readInner1` and `readInnerPage` are both defined as calls to function `readUint32Aligned`. The only difference between the two macros is that `readInnerPage` returns the value found at four bytes past the value that would be returned by `readInner1` given the same page and slot arguments.

Function `readUint32Aligned` is essentially just a call to function `toHost`, which is not defined in the code sample you provided. However, my guess would be that `toHost` converts an unsigned 32-bit integer from [network byte order into host order](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/network_byte_orders.htm).